# Passing Interfaces into Dictionary key's

Tags: c#-4.0

I have been following following coreclr for a little while and I am new to programming. My question is why do they pass interfaces into Dictionary's especially the key value?

//

- // Allocate a new Dictionary containing a copy of the old values, plus the new value. We have to do this manually to
- // minimize allocations of IEnumerators, etc.
- //
- Dictionary newValues = new Dictionary(current.m_localValues.Count + (hadPreviousValue ? 0 : 1));

My understanding is that interface is to implemented by a class. Once implemented it can call/use functions or store data in the classes properties/ variables. **I am missing some understanding of interfaces** and their use cases but I do not know what that it.

Why do you instantiate a variable to an interface or pass an interface into a parameter? My understanding is you will then have an instance of that variable which still can't hold values nor change state through methods.

Comment: Are you trying to ask that why interface is used instead of class that implemented the interface ?

Comment: Partially, I do not understand why not a class I stead of a interface. But with regards to the dictionary that's uses integer as a key, or some enum, e.g. a ordered object. So why is interface used then? I cannot connect those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain.

1. Interface is contract. It just contains method without implementation. Now it may possible that that interface is being implemented by any number of class.

   ```
   public interface IEntity {    int Id {get;set;} }

   public class Student : IEntity {    public int Id {get;set;} // Interface Property }

   public class Teacher : IEntity {    public int Id {get;set;} // Interface Property }

   Dictionary<IEntity,object> obj = new Dictionary<IEntity,object>(); Student s = new Student(); Teacher t = new Teacher(); obj.Add(s,any object); obj.Add(t,any object);
   ```

This is because of interface that your dictionary can hold reference of both type ( Student and Teacher).

In .NET when any object is created it is uniquely identify by GetHashCode() method. // You can find more detail on this on MSDN.

Also Dictionary not means that keys must be only primitive type. This is the reason it is good if you have more than one key ( Like composite key in Database) so it allow you to identify uniquely based on your custom implementation.

2. Now second Generic.

   ```
   public class PersonInfo<T> where T : IEntity
   {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public T Entity {get;set;}
   }

   PersonInfo<Student> student = new PersonInfo<Student>();
   student.T = new Student();
   student.Name = "";

   PersonInfo<Teacher> Teacher = new PersonInfo<Teacher>();
   teacher.T=  new Teacher();
   teacher.Name = "";
   ```

Answer (score 0):

When you have interface. It not actually interface. You always have a reference to object with that interface. And that object is the one responsible for comparison in dictionary

The benefit is not difference from using class as a key. Dictionary can be used as list to iterate KeyValuePair to take key to do some operation. But using interface means you can store various type of class with same interface instead of just one type. Which is decoupled and more flexible